# python can't read key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dict from AWS:

https://pastebin.com/pG02WANu

and i'm trying to get the Name key on:

HealthChecks->HealthCheckConfig->AlarmIdentifier->Name

but it seems python stops at HealthCheckConfig:

```
for alarm in alarms['HealthChecks']:
    print('Alarm: %s' % alarm )
    if unicode('AlarmIdentifier') in alarm['HealthCheckConfig']:
        print('Alarm Name: %s' % alarm['AlarmIdentifier'] )
```

i get:

```
Alarm: {u'HealthCheckConfig': {u'InsufficientDataHealthStatus': '... u'MetricName': 'HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count'}}

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lambda_function.py", line 283, in <module>
    main()
  File "lambda_function.py", line 279, in main
    lambda_handler('start', 'test')
  File "lambda_function.py", line 263, in lambda_handler
    freeSWITCH.setHC(fsNode + ' CPU Health', aws_creds, 0)
  File "/home/admin/scripts/myscript/myscript.py", line 81, in setHC
    print('Alarm Name: %s' % alarm['AlarmIdentifier'] )
KeyError: 'AlarmIdentifier'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: key `AlarmIdentifier` is not in `alarm` but in `alarm['HealthCheckConfig']` no ?

Comment: Please post (at least some of) the data, instead of a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked, @PRMoureu pointed my mistake... I guess i've been at it too long today.

```
alarms = client.list_health_checks(MaxItems='2')
print('alarms: %s' % alarms)
for alarm in alarms['HealthChecks']:
    print('Alarm: %s\n==============================' % alarm )
    if unicode('AlarmIdentifier') in alarm['HealthCheckConfig']:
        print('FOUND')
        print('Alarm Name: %s' % alarm['HealthCheckConfig']['AlarmIdentifier']['Name'] )
```